# What is maximum monotonic increase/ decrease for each group in my dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe where I have values for my 'linear' variable and there 30 different groups. I want to calculate/count the maximum number of times there was a monotonic increase/decrease in values for each group in the dataframe.

```
Linear | Series | Basal
70 | Night 1 | increase       
72 | Night 1 | increase
75 | Night 1 | decrease
65 | Night 1 | decrease
100 | Night 2 | decrease
90 | Night 2 | decrease
91 | Night 2 | increase
80 | Night 2 | decrease
```

The results should be

```
Night 1: Increase 2 Decrease 2
Night 2: Increase 1 Decrease 2
```

Comment: Can the 'Linear' term be ignored, ie should we count trends based on the row order that's provided (where Linear 65 follows Linear 75 in Night 1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach could be to use `rle` to get the max runs:

```
maxmv <- function(x, val) with(rle(x), max(lengths[values == val]))

df %>%
  group_by(Series) %>%
  summarise(increase = maxmv(Basal, "increase"),
            decrease = maxmv(Basal, "decrease"))   

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  Series  increase decrease
  <chr>      <int>    <int>
1 Night 1        2        2
2 Night 2        1        2
```

Same approach using base r:

```
aggregate(Basal ~ Series, df, FUN = function(y) c(increase = maxmv(y, "increase"),
                                                  decrease = maxmv(y, "decrease")))

   Series Basal.increase Basal.decrease
1 Night 1              2              2
2 Night 2              1              2
```

Comment: Ooh, I didn't know about `rle`, that's handy.

Comment: @Jay: Just a corollary question. If there is a way that I can extract the elements (column: linear) for each of these series:

Comment: If you want to keep that info in the result you can use `mutate` instead of `summarise` in the `dplyr` approach above.

Comment: @Jay you are correct. But I want entries corresponding to only if it forming a part of my maximum "increase" or "decrease" sequence. I don't want to capture rows/ values where it is a single increase/decrease

Comment: So, using your example data, you'd expect to retain all rows except the last one?  If not you'd better ask a new question and provide your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach with `dplyr`. I'm sure there's a more elegant way there, but this gives the desired output.

First, we mark the new directional trends within each group (by recording if the row's `Basal` matches the prior one), and take the running count. This assigns a different number to each new trend within a group. Then we count how many records are within each trend, and keep the longest.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Series) %>%
  mutate(new_trend = Basal != lag(Basal, default = ""),
         trend_count = cumsum(new_trend)) %>%
  count(Series, Basal, trend_count, sort = T) %>%
  select(-trend_count) %>%
  group_by(Series, Basal) %>%
  top_n(1) %>%
  spread(Basal, n)

#Selecting by n
## A tibble: 2 x 3
## Groups:   Series [2]
#  Series  decrease increase
#  <chr>      <int>    <int>
#1 Night 1        2        2
#2 Night 2        2        1
```

Data used:

```
df <- read.table(header = T, stringsAsFactors = F, 
text = "Linear  Series  Basal
70  'Night 1'  increase       
72  'Night 1'  increase
75  'Night 1'  decrease
65  'Night 1'  decrease
100 'Night 2'  decrease
90  'Night 2'  decrease
91  'Night 2'  increase
80  'Night 2'  decrease")
```

Comment: Just a corollary question. If there is a way that I can extract the elements (column: linear) for each of these series: